# How to get Twilio account verification number from an API request?

Tags: javascript, api, post, get, twilio

I am facing an issue in JavaScript: I want to get a Twilio account verification number from an API request.

```
Twilio Account SID: Axxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
Twilio Auth Token: exxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
```

I read the [Twilio documentation](https://www.twilio.com/docs) but I can't find any such API request. Which API request should I use to get Twilio account verification number??

Comment: Please remove the screenshot so it doesn’t expose your token. Also change your token now that it is no longer secured. https://support.twilio.com/hc/en-us/articles/223136027-Auth-Tokens-and-How-to-Change-Them

Comment: ok sorry my mistake remove screenshot [@](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9750066/alan)

Answer (score 0):

It looks like doing an HTTPS GET request to https://verify.twilio.com/v2/Services with your account SID and Auth Token returns an object with an array of Verify Services. This doesn't appear to be documented.

Comment: thanks i try GET request to https://verify.twilio.com/v2/Services but it does not show my Twilio account phone # [@](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9750066/alan)

Comment: No array of Verify Services display  [@](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9750066/alan)

Comment: Are you using VerifyV2? https://www.twilio.com/console/verify/dashboard/ (make sure V2) - https://www.twilio.com/blog/introducing-verify-v2-public-beta.

Comment: yes using this api request https://verify.twilio.com/v2/Services but it shows `"services": []` [@](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9750066/alan)

Comment: Next question, I assume you created a Verify V2 Service? You can this via the API or via the Twilio console, https://www.twilio.com/docs/verify/api, `Create a Verification Service` code example or https://www.twilio.com/console/verify/services.

Comment: how can i created a  Verify V2 Service? [@](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9750066/alan)

Comment: can you please tell me how can i get `twilio Active Numbers`? any api request? [@](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9750066/alan)

Comment: That is another question but it was already answered, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63296967/list-my-phone-number-inventory-inside-twilio-flex