# Twilio how to manage local phone numbers through api

Tags: twilio, twilio-api

I am trying to move my account off of using local numbers and onto toll free numbers.

I would like to get a list of all my local numbers.  The incoming_phone_numbers api does not seem to return the Type attribute which tells me local vs toll free.

I believe I need to use the Active Number api, which is in preview, to get that info https://www.twilio.com/docs/phone-numbers/global-catalog/api/active-numbers

I am receiving a 404 response when I use the below script.

I've found post of people talking about this api, but all the comments were about the issue I am having with no resolution https://stackoverflow.com/a/63297180/3599659

```
from twilio.rest import Client
import keyring
import requests
from requests.auth import HTTPBasicAuth

account_sid = keyring.get_password("twilio", "account_sid")
auth_token  = keyring.get_password("twilio", "auth_token")

client = Client(account_sid, auth_token)

numbers = client.incoming_phone_numbers.list(limit=1)

print(f"getting info for {numbers[0].sid}")

response = requests.get(f"https://preview.twilio.com/Numbers/ActiveNumbers/{numbers[0].sid}", auth=HTTPBasicAuth(account_sid, auth_token))

if not response:
    print(f"Request for active numbers failed. status code:{response.status_code}. {response.content}")
    quit()

print(response.content)
```

Answer (score 2):

This API is in Private Developer Preview. I am not sure if it still open to accepting new customers. I am looking to discover this.

Comment: O interesting.  I assumed Developer Preview meant no gaurantees on it working.  Figured if I needed to sign up for it, I would get a 401 instead of 404.

Answer (score 0):

It does cost $0.005 per call but if you only have US numbers you can make a call to the [lookups api](https://www.twilio.com/docs/phone-numbers/global-catalog/api/active-numbers) requesting carrier information for the number.

```
response = requests.get(f"https://lookups.twilio.com/v1/PhoneNumbers/{numbers[0].phoneNumber}?Type=carrier", auth=HTTPBasicAuth(account_sid, auth_token))
```

This should list the carrier name as either `Twilio - SMS/MMS-SVR` or `Twilio - Toll-Free - SMS-Sybase365/MMS-SVR` so you can identify the toll free numbers that way. This is assuming the numbers were issued by twilio and haven't been ported in etc.